# SBT won't autocomplet on keys defined in globalSettings of an AutoPlugin

Tags: sbt

```
object BlaBlaPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val blabla = taskKey[Unit]("")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    blabla := println("Hello")
  )
}
```

Gives:

```
> bla
{invalid input}
> blabla
Hello
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 22-Dec-2015 00:33:21
```

Why wouldn't the autocompletion work?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify,

```
> bla[tab]
{invalid input}
```

where `[tab]` is actually a key stroke.

This might be a bug and/or limitation of sbt. Please file this on Github issue.